# How Secure is Storing Cryptographic Information into the CPU Register instead of RAM

Tags: cold-boot-attack

I read about [Tresor / TreVisor / Armored](https://www1.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/tresor).

How Secure is Storing Cryptographic Information into the CPU Debug-Register over storing it into the RAM?

And why is it currently not much used?

I know that this will mitigate a Cold-Boot-Attack which is one of the ways to "break" a Full Disk Encryption but what are further uses?

As far as I know is the Programming of this functionality not so much more complicated as "normal" use of the RAM.

Comment: You want to use TPM (Trusted Platform Module) for key storage. Impracticality of tying up key CPU resources for storage aside, registers are controlled by scheduler and are routinely cached. That is, your keys will end up elsewhere no matter what you do. That is, unless you also write your own kernel that implements custom scheduler.

Comment: I edit the Question to make more clear what I really wanted to answered ;)

Comment: I have the same question. TRESOR seems a great solution against CBA. Why is it currently not much used? Storing keys in debug registers are not feasible?

Answer (score 3):

An answer obviously depends on the kind of CPU you are talking about.

For example, with general-purpose registers on a modern x86 CPU, you have several problems:

1. CPU registers are mostly 64 bits wide. To store a cryptographic key of decent size, you'd need at least two registers. This is a problem because the number of registers on x86s are very limited (it's even worse with older x86 CPUs)
2. CPU registers are the main "work area" of a CPU, so you can't store a cryptographic key there for longer periods of time because there is basically no protection/isolation in effect - any register, except some special purpose registers (which, however, are needed for correct functioning of the operating system/task switching etc, and therefore can't be used to store cryptographic keys), can be accessed by anyone who can get the processor to execute a few instructions. This isn't true for memory, which can be protected from access by unauthorized programs.
3. On operating systems which support multitasking (so, basically every current OS), when a task switch occurs, all the register contents are saved to RAM when a task is preempted and reloaded from RAM when the task is given the CPU again. This happens dozens, if not hundreds of times per second. So your cryptographic keys would end up stored in memory anyway. They might also end up swapped out to disk when a page that stored a currently stopped task was swapped out to disk to make room for another process.

*Edit*: As your followup comment and my repsonse to it explains, you can work around some of these problems using special purpose registers which are usually unused. However, there are still problems that don't seem to make this worthwile:

1. Your OS must cooperate - if it happens to use these special-purpose registers for the purpose they were actually designed for, your keys get overwritten, and your data may be trashed without you noticing it.
2. You're still only protected against cold-boot attacks (assuming no state actually leaves the CPU, which isn't so easy to guarantee due to task preemption) and against low-privilege attacks that can't get access to ring 0. When your kernel gets compromised, your keys can still be easily stolen with just a few simple CPU instructions. It might be even easier to steal them in that case, because you'd know exactly where to look for them. So you're not adding any security except against cold boot and maybe some DMA attacks (when an unprivileged program stores keys in RAM, other unprivileged programs can't read them, either).

I don't know how prevalent cold boot attacks for key extraction actually are in the wild. I'd assume state-sponsored special ops teams, plus your occasional gadget freak might pull them off. But I'd worry much more about compromised OS kernels than about cold boot attacks.

Comment: But then explain why TRESOR work (beside the DMA attack)

Comment: Tresor uses the debug registers, which are usually used for debugging. Which is neat, because if you try to debug the code to get at the keys, you might overwrite the keys in the process. The debug registers are special purpose registers which are protected from access by anyone except ring 0 (the most privileged code, usually the kernel). Still, it's not foolproof. The aim seems to be to protect the keys against key extraction by a cold boot attack.

Comment: I edit the Question to make more clear what I really wanted to answered ;)